# my Xperia l not starting

Tags: boot, rom

I tried to install a custom rom on my Xperia L,but it aborted.
Now my handset isn't booting up, when powered on it just shows SONY logo.
What should I do now ?

Comment: It would be good to know how or why it aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flash the custom ROM again, starting with flashing the `boot` partition from `fastboot`. Before doing that re-download the whole ROM and if you can, check it for defects. The fact that the phone draws the SONY logo proves that the bootloader is still working, so you should be able to do this. Pulling out the battery and powering up the phone while keeping the volume up key pressed will put the phone in fastboot mode (the blue LED will light up), from which you can continue.

Answer (score -2):

you need to complete the flash.. download xperial l generic rom and flash it again..